# Error in Setting up Spring MVC Application Without Maven

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web-applications

I'm totally beginner to Spring MVC and hence I was following the steps on this tutorial https://www.pegaxchange.com/2018/01/24/java-web-project-with-spring-framework/ but I'm stuck at an annoying error which I get after editing my spring-web-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.pgx.java.web" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
        location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

I receive the following errors:

- Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd)
- Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd)

I went through many answers on stack overflow, nothing seems to work.

I'm using Spring MVC 5.0.2